# Select2 with custom "text" property name

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I am trying to use [**Select2**](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) with a different property name for **text**. I have a array of objects which have **name** property. I am trying to use that object directly in select2 as given below

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <input type="hidden" id="selectElement"/>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function format(item) {
    return item.name;
};

$("#selectElement").select2({
    placeholder: 'Select ...',
    data: [{id:0, name: "Home"},{id:1, name: "About Us"},{id:2, name: "Reach Us"}],
    formatResult: format,
    formatSelection: format,
});
```

As demonstrated in this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hevhuxpo/) the options get populated correctly. But when we enter some text matching any of the existing options, the select2 displays **No Matches Found** in-spite of having a match.

What am I missing here, which results in default matching not working ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you also have to redefine [`matcher`](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#doc-matcher) function:

```
$("#selectElement").select2({
    placeholder: 'Select ...',
    data: [{id:0, name: "Home"},{id:1, name: "About Us"},{id:2, name: "Reach Us"}],
    formatResult: format,
    formatSelection: format,
    matcher: function(term, text, option) {
        return option.name.toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase())>=0;
    }
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/hevhuxpo/4/

Comment: `Migrating from Select2 3.5:` "they have been renamed to templateSelection and templateResult and their signatures have changed as well" [read more...](https://select2.org/upgrading/migrating-from-35#renamed-templating-options)